# What is the best way to validate and parse complex fields in Pentaho kettle?

Tags: database, validation, pentaho, etl, kettle

What is the best way to validate fields in a row and if invalid, correct it to the right form?

The simplest example would be checking phone number field (can come in variant formats -> 111-111-1111, (111) 111-1111 etc), and we would ideally want to validate these and standardize to one form (lets say: 1111111111). One way to do this is to use filter rows and then use a regex, or we can use data validator. But this will only tell us what data is invalid but not actually format it for us. We can then use Javascript modified value step to write a js script to do this. But I am guessing there is a better way (or a built in integration that I haven't come across) that would do these basic validations. Or is it recommended to just dump rows containing invalid fields in a separate csv file and then use a script to parse it separately?

Comment: I wouldn't quite second your statement *But this will only tell us what data is invalid but not actually format it for us.* Actually, when using regular expressions with groups you are half way done with formatting since you have all your logical components identified. In your case above you would have three groups of digits that you would concatenate into one. Could you edit your question to add maybe two or three more examples? I think this would make the complexity of the required transformations clearer and someone might come up with a concrete suggestion.

Comment: That's looks like a clear cut regex application. I would go with a regex step with capturing groups, as mentioned above, followed by the filter rows step to filter out incorrect data and then you can collect the groups back in any format you want (string operations, calculator, user defined java expression, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

g'day

i use the excellent 'replace in string' step to handle this circumstance

you can cumulatively apply rules for removing bad char from strings within the single step - it is really easy to use for single-char fixes like what you have described, and best of all, it also allows you to search based on regex as well - in a single step you have documented your standardisation and produced the clean output

in your case, i would create two 'rules' to replace `(` and `)` with nothing - however, the `-` is a little trickier; you need a rule for each removal of a single char, so you would need to know the maximum number of `-` in a single data field, then add this many lines to your 'replace in string' step

if this is unpalatable, consider the 'user defined java expression' and a call to `replace`, eg: `( (t0 != null) ? t0.replace("-","") : t0 )`

as i stated, each 'fix' is applied in sequential order - the `In stream field` is the input field-name, whereas the `Outstream field` is left blank instructing d.i. to modify the field itself - here's a more complex example where i search for regex and replace them with nothing, escape for the case where i escape a `"` double-quote:

```
In stream field Out stream field    use RegEx   Search                                          Replace with
sc_srcuri                           N           {Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory}                
re_s_sciname                        Y           ["]                                             \\"
re_s_sciname                        Y           .[\x08]                                                     
re_s_sciname                        Y           .[\x08]                                                     
re_s_sciname                        Y           .[\x08]                                                     
re_s_sciname                        Y           [*]                                                         
re_s_sciname                        Y           \s*$                                                        
re_s_sciname                        Y           ^\s*
```

notice i am removing up to three 'delete' control-codes `[\x08]` from this particular string?